# Where and how do I set the permissions so my reporting services that resides on server A can access a folder path on Server B?

Tags: reporting-services

When I run my report, my image does not display because the reporting services that sits on ServerA can't access the path on ServerB.

How do I set up the permissions?

The reporting services log states:

WARN: An error occurred retrieving the external resource 'file://serverB/IMAGES//2015\someimage.jpg' : Access to the path '\ServerB\2015\someimage.jpg' is denied.

Is it in the security section within SQL Management Studio?

Is it in the Site Settings of reporting services ?

Is the security tab of the properties of the folders themselves?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See if this can help you out http://www.joellipman.com/articles/microsoft/sql-server/ssrs/530-ssrs-external-images-dont-display.html

Comment: Thank you! The execution account is what is needed.